# Is a symmetric matrix with a positive determinant a covariance matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, random-variables, covariance

A covariance matrix has a positive determinant (the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues which are all positive).

Is the other direction also true? That is, if a symmetric real-valued matrix has a a positive determinant, is it then a covariance matrix?

Comment: No. You need all the principal minors to also be positive.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}-2&-1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$ is symmetric and has positive determinant.

Comment: $-I_2$ would make a simpler counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

From the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) any *positive-semidefinate* matrix $C$ has a square root $S:=C^{1/2}$ matrix such that $C=SS^T$. Now let $X=(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$, where $P(X_i=\pm 1)=1/2$, so that:

$$E[(SX-E[SX])(SX-E[SX])^T]=E[SXX^TS^T]=SS^T=C.$$

Note that positive-semidefinite implies positive determinant, but is also stronger as it guarantees all eigenvalues are non-negative. blueInk's example in the comments above has negative eigenvalues.